# How do I compare dates in the same column based on criteria from another column in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df with u_id, date, order, and I need to add a column that gives a date difference between each order for each user. E.g:

```
u_id | date       | order
001  | 2019-01-01 |  1
001  | 2019-01-10 |  2
001  | 2019-01-15 |  3
002  | 2019-05-03 |  1
002  | 2019-05-06 |  2
...
```

What I'm aiming for is this:

```
u_id | date       | order | date_difference
001  | 2019-01-01 |  1    |    NaT
001  | 2019-01-10 |  2    |   9 days
001  | 2019-01-15 |  3    |   5 days
002  | 2019-05-03 |  1    |    NaT
002  | 2019-05-06 |  2    |   3 days
...
```

`date_difference` col doesn't necessarily need to say days.

I'm using pandas with python 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `groupby`:

```
df['date_difference'] = df.groupby('u_id')['date'].diff()
```

Or without `groupby` given the correct ordering:

```
df['date_difference'] = df.date.diff().where(df.u_id==df.u_id.shift())
```

Output:

```
   u_id       date  order date_difference
0     1 2019-01-01      1             NaT
1     1 2019-01-10      2          9 days
2     1 2019-01-15      3          5 days
3     2 2019-05-03      1             NaT
4     2 2019-05-06      2          3 days
```

Comment: ```df['date_difference'] = df.groupby('u_id')['date'].diff()``` did the job, thanks!

Comment: nice one, diff and shift will come in handy